# How to build logistic regression model in SparkR

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to Spark as well as SparkR. I have successfully installed Spark and SparkR.

When I tried to build Logistic regression model with R and Spark over csv file stored in HDFS, I got the  error "incorrect number of dimensions".

My Code is :

```
points <- cache(lapplyPartition(textFile(sc, "hdfs://localhost:54310/Henry/data.csv"), readPartition))

collect(points)

w <- runif(n=D, min = -1, max = 1)

cat("Initial w: ", w, "\n")

# Compute logistic regression gradient for a matrix of data points
gradient <- function(partition) {
  partition = partition[[1]]
  Y <- partition[, 1] # point labels (first column of input file)
  X <- partition[, -1] # point coordinates
  # For each point (x, y), compute gradient function

  dot <- X %*% w
  logit <- 1 / (1 + exp(-Y * dot))
  grad <- t(X) %*% ((logit - 1) * Y)
  list(grad)
}


for (i in 1:iterations) {
  cat("On iteration ", i, "\n")
  w <- w - reduce(lapplyPartition(points, gradient), "+")
}
```

Error Message is:

```
On iteration  1 
Error in partition[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
Calls: do.call ... func -> FUN -> FUN -> Reduce -> <Anonymous> -> FUN -> FUN
Execution halted
14/09/27 01:38:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 181.0 (TID 189)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
14/09/27 01:38:13 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 181.0 (TID 189, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException: 
        edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:125)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
14/09/27 01:38:13 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 181.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Error in .jcall(getJRDD(rdd), "Ljava/util/List;", "collect") : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 181.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 181.0 (TID 189, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException: edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:125) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262) org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229) org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62) org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54) org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) Driver stacktrace:
```

Dimension of data (sample) :

```
data <- read.csv("/home/Henry/data.csv")

dim(data)
```

[1]  17 541

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Comment: I think you forgot to show us the result of `dim(data)`.

Comment: @voidHead, I have added output of dim(data)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `textFile()` reads some text data and return a distributed collection of **strings**, each of which corresponds to a line of the text file. Therefore later in the program `partition[, -1]` fails. The program's real intent seems to be treating `points` as a distributed collection of data frames. We are working on providing data frame support in SparkR soon ([SPARKR-1](https://sparkr.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKR-1)).

To resolve the issue, simply manipulate your `partition` using string operations to extract `X`, `Y` correctly. Some other ways include (I think you've probably seen this before) producing a different type of distributed collection from the beginning as is done here: [examples/logistic_regression.R](https://github.com/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg/blob/master/examples/logistic_regression.R).

Comment: At the same time reduce and lapplyPartition are being removed (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7230)  from the interface, so when DataFrames will be available, this program will be completely non-functional